# No cursor/caret in Linux VMC under Windows Hyper-V?

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have just installed CentOS-7, Minimal Installation, into a Hyper-V VM under Windows Server 2008 R2.

When I Start the VM from **Hyper-V Manager** it opens a window it calls **Virtual Machine Connection**, effectively a text-only console.  There I get to log into Linux via standard console prompt, and am left in Bash in this window.  All fine, and very traditional UN*X.

The problem is I get no caret/cursor, flashing or otherwise, in the command-line window, while I'm logging in or afterward.  This is going to make it extremely difficult to utilise any Bash command-line/history editing!  (Same situation if I make the window full-screen.)

The question is: is the missing cursor/caret the "fault"/"responsibility" of the **VMC** (for which I can find no option or documentation about this) or of the Linux console (e.g. an `stty` argument)?

STOP PRESS:
I just tried going into `vi`, and a flashing caret appears inside it.  When I quit back to the console the caret remains.  But I don't wish to do that every time!  So this looks more like a Linux terminal issue than the VMC itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also noticed this with CentOS 7.1 (upgraded from 7.0) running on Hyper-V (Windows 8.1).

You can get the cursor back even at the logon prompt by pressing the Windows Key and right arrow. Does this open up another console? You can go back to the original console by pressing the Windows Key and left arrow.

It's another option to opening up vi just to close it to get the cursor back.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue with the text cursor after migrating Centos 7.1 from virtual-box to hyper-v [host is windows 10] (and after rebuilding initramfs in rescue mode using `dracut -f` to get it to boot)

I ended up installed the hyper-v integration services (some integration is inbuilt but maybe mine didn't detect after migration)., anyway:

1. Download the [iso](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55106) - I used LinuxIC-4.3.5.x86_64.iso
2. "insert" using the Hyper-v setting
3. Mount the vitual cd drive

   - `sudo mkdir /media/cdrom`
   - `sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom`
4. Install the integration services.

   - `cd /media/cdrom`
   - `chmod +x ./install.sh`
   - `sudo ./install.sh`
5. Reboot. (I shutdown and turned back on but should work)

   - `sudo reboot`

Other helpful links:

- [Download Linux hyper-v integration services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55106)
- [Supported Linux and FreeBSD virtual machines for Hyper-V on Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/Supported-Linux-and-FreeBSD-virtual-machines-for-Hyper-V-on-Windows)